# what's i missing with this script geolocation redirect

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geo

what was one of the scripts that I have. this does not work according to the target country code

```js
//OFFER WAP
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
  navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
  navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
  var target = []; // 
  target.US = "https://www.google.com"; // 
  target.AU = "https://stackoverflow.com/"; // 
  target.All = "https://www.facebook.com/"; // 
  setTimeout("document.location = urls;", 1500);
}

function geoip(g) {
  window.top.location.href = target[g.country_code] || target.All
}
(function(g, e, o, i, p) {
  i = g.createElement(e), p = g.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  i.async = 0;
  i.src = o;
  p.parentNode.insertBefore(i, p)
})(document, 'script', 'http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/?callback=geoip');
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Please Wait...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1500">
<script src='http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Just fyi, you are creating an array but `target.US` and the other assignments are not how you add array elements. I think you just want a plain object, `target={}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the initialization of `target` inside the `if` block for various user agents. If the user agent doesn't match any of them, `target` is left undefined, and then `target[g.country_code]` gets an error.

You should initialize the variable to an empty object before the `if`, and also put the default `target.All` there. If you want location-specific targets depending on the user agent, you can add those inside the `if`.

Another problem is that there's no `country_code` property in the response. The JSON looks like:

```
geoip({
  "city": "Woburn",
  "country": {
    "name": "United States",
    "code": "US"
  },
  "location": {
    "accuracy_radius": 5,
    "latitude": 42.4897,
    "longitude": -71.1595,
    "time_zone": "America/New_York"
  },
  "ip": "71.192.114.133"
});
```

The country code is in `g.country.code`, not `g.country_code`.

```js
var target = { All: "https://www.facebook.com/" };

//OFFER WAP
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
  navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
  navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
  target.US = "https://www.google.com"; // 
  target.AU = "https://stackoverflow.com/"; // 
  setTimeout("document.location = urls;", 1500);
}

function geoip(g) {
  window.top.location.href = target[g.country.code] || target.All
}
(function(g, e, o, i, p) {
  i = g.createElement(e), p = g.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  i.async = 0;
  i.src = o;
  p.parentNode.insertBefore(i, p)
})(document, 'script', 'http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/?callback=geoip');
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Please Wait...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1500">
<script src='http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: I already gave it. the real problem is the script is not able to work on the ip was just headed to target all. how people can be diverted automatically to the geo that I pairs such as the us

Comment: There's no `country_code` property in the response. It should be `g.country.code`.